# Creating JSP Page/Servlet using my Axis2 Webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jsp, apache-axis

we created a webservice with Axis2/Spring/Hibernate/Maven. It's packaged as .aar file.
Now I like to create a JSP-File or servlet to use this webservice. 
Is it possible to deploy this file in the .aar, too? Or have I to create a new project (packaged as .war file) and use the webservice, there?

The JSP-File is only for administration ...

Thx, Simone

Comment: you can use the same project.

Comment: Thx. Ok, I will create a jsp file? And have to add a web.xml? Are you sure it will be deployed with a .aar file?

Comment: no, it will be deployed as .war file.

Comment: But I like to deploy the Axis2 webservice as .aar file... I can't change this packaging.

Comment: you should decide whether you can put it in .war or create .ear and add to it along with .war.